# Unix --Read Content of File1 and Search and replace with new values

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have File1 having couple of columns and having around 10000 rows like below

```
VALUE1      VALUE2
ABC11111    9075ABC3
ABC22222    3456ABC4
ABC33333    6786ABC5
ABC44444    9846ABC6
ABC55555    3276ABC7
```

The other file FILE2 have multiple rows (1M+) and having VALUE1 (ABC11111,ABC22222) from FILE1

```
    We Need to complete ABC11111 Work
    Tomorrow ABC22222 is Holiday
    Hello How are you ABC11111 doing
    His name is ABC55555 Ramesh
```

I want To check if VALUE1 is present in FILE2 and if yes need to replace it with VALUE2 (Corresponding of VALUE1), below like output

```
    We Need to complete ABC11111 Work  --- > We Need to complete 9075ABC3 Work
    Tomorrow ABC22222 is Holiday      ----->  Tomorrow 3456ABC4 is Holiday
    Hello How are you ABC11111 doing   -----> Hello How are you 9075ABC3 doing
    His name is ABC55555 Ramesh   ------->  His name is 3276ABC7 Ramesh
```

Please Help how this can be achieved in Linux

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; you're expected to show your effort (eg, research, code); consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide the code you've tried so far and the (wrong) output generated by your code; `sed` or a `bash` looping construct would work but would be extremely slow compared to a solution using `awk`, `perl`, etc.

Comment: There must be loads of similar questions with suitable answers. I'd suggest you search a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

> how this can be achieved in Linux

I suggest taking look at `-f` option of [`sed`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), it allows you to load sedscript file into `sed`, if you need to do replacement as follows

```
ABC11111    9075ABC3
ABC22222    3456ABC4
ABC33333    6786ABC5
ABC44444    9846ABC6
ABC55555    3276ABC7
```

then sedscript might look as follows

```
s/ABC11111/9075ABC3/g
s/ABC22222/3456ABC4/g
s/ABC33333/6786ABC5/g
s/ABC44444/9846ABC6/g
s/ABC55555/3276ABC7/g
```

and lets name it `replaces.sed` and your file `file.txt` then

```
sed -f replaces.sed file.txt
```

will output to standard output file with described changes applied. As your replacement has *around 10000 rows* you should find to way automatically convert such file into sedscript, which is not hard to do in GNU `AWK`. Be careful if replacements might contain character of special meaning for `sed` e.g. `.`, this is not problem if all replacements consist solely of ASCII letters and digits as is case for snippet you shown.